# "Not an Answer" Flag Declined, Answer Deleted, Can't see Answer

Tags: discussion, support, flags

First of all, I realize there are a lot of *"Why was my flag declined?"* posts on Meta, so I apologize for asking another one, but I'm more curious as to the answer that I flagged and not the reason it was declined.

Basically, I flagged an answer to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371650/css-flex-last-and-first-item-in-a-row-selector/29285826#29285826) on March 26th, last Thursday, and over the weekend, the flag was declined. Today, when I casually checked on my flagging status, I noticed a new section on the right:

```
1 declined
```

This being my first declined flag I was curious what this meant, so I read the comments from the moderator, which were:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

It makes sense, I must've flagged something that I shouldn't have, so I went to see what that answer was, but at some point after the flag was declined, the answer was deleted. Now I'm afraid that I have forgotten the contents of this answer, and since I have less than 10k reputation I'm left in the dark.

Again, this is more of a curiosity issue than a *light the fires, grab the pitchforks I did nothing wrong!* issue, so if the answer is that there is no way for me to see the contents of the answer I flagged, that would be fine.

Comment: The answer says [_You can add :last-child !important;_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29285826/426671) and you flagged it as low quality meaning it is unsalvageable and should be deleted immediately. Obviously the mod who processed the flag, disagreed and declined your flag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer was deleted by the owner.

There was a "this is not answer" comment (which is actually wrong, because it is an answer, just a wrong one) and a down-vote so this is probably what prompted the owner to delete the answer.

I wasn't the moderator who handled the flag in this case but I think I know what the moderator who did was thinking.

You actually used the "Very Low Quality" flag, not the "Not An Answer" flag - but in either case the flag should have been declined. It was an attempt at an answer, but it was wrong (did I say that already?). In that case down-vote and move on. Moderators don't need to be involved in cases like this.

I repeat if you see an answer that's wrong **down-vote it and move on**. *Don't flag it*. If you do there's a very good chance that your flag will be declined.

Comment: That makes sense. I really couldn't remember the contents of the answer, so I had no idea what the flag comments were referring to, but this cleared it up. Thanks again!

Comment: Is it possible to have a more generic title for this question? had a similar issue and was about to post when I finally found this, just the flag was different.